# Spring OAuth2: Always returning invalid token

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, oauth-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I am trying to implement an OAuth2-Server with one Resource Server using Spring Boot.
I am able to request tokens but if I use them to request resources from the Resource server the result is always 'invalid token'.

This is the authorization server configuration:

```java
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class AuthserverConfiguration extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
        endpoints.authorizationCodeServices(authorizationCodeServices())
        // injects the Spring Security authentication manager (set up in WebSecurityConfiguration )
                .authenticationManager(authenticationManager)
                .tokenStore(tokenStore());
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer security) throws Exception {
        // configure security for /oauth/check_token and /oauth/token_key endpoint
        security.tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
                .checkTokenAccess("permitAll()"); // should be isAuthenticated()

    }
    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("clientId").secret("{noop}clientsecret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("authorization_code", "refresh_token", "password")
                .scopes("read");
    }
    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore() {
        return new InMemoryTokenStore();
    }
    @Bean
    protected AuthorizationCodeServices authorizationCodeServices() {
        // creates authorization codes, stores the codes in memory.
        return new InMemoryAuthorizationCodeServices();
    }
}
```

WebSecurityConfiguration is:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
@Configuration
@Order(SecurityProperties.BASIC_AUTH_ORDER - 20)
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication()
                .withUser("user").password("{noop}password").roles("USER");
        /* for now testing with inMemoryAuthentication, later I want to use: 
         * auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService); */
    }
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            .requestMatchers().antMatchers("/login", "/oauth/authorize", "/oauth/confirm_access")
            .and()
            .formLogin().loginPage("/login").permitAll().failureUrl("/login?error")
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated();
    }

    @Bean(name = BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
}
```

And the UserInfoController:

```
@RestController
public class UserInfoController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user")
    public Principal userInfo(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal user) {
        return user;
    }
}
```

pom.xml contains the following dependencies:+

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security.oauth</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-oauth2</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

The Resource server on the other hand is a standard Spring Boot project with tomcat, listening to `GET /products` (returning a list in JSON format) on port 8081.
The servers main class is annotated with `@EnableResourceServer` and its configuration contains:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    resource:
      user-info-uri: http://localhost:8090/user
```

where 8090 is the port of above mentioned authentication server.

Testing with curl:

```
> curl clientId:clientsecret@localhost:8090/oauth/token -d grant_type=password -d username=user -d password=password -d scope=read`
{"access_token":"1cdd6dc2-42fe-4b55-b16d-78d189a88cc4","token_type":"bearer","refresh_token":"d59d78b5-43c8-4d12-b4ee-007da8548744","expires_in":43199,"scope":"read"}

> curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer 1cdd6dc2-42fe-4b55-b16d-78d189a88cc4' 'localhost:8090/oauth/check_token?token=1cdd6dc2-42fe-4b55-b16d-78d189a88cc4'
{"exp":1561956415,"user_name":"user","authorities":["ROLE_USER"],"client_id":"clientId","scope":["read"]}+ set +o xtrace
```

The token seems to be valid and recognized (if I tamper with the token I get a different error: "unrecognized token").

But if I try to request data from the Resource Server using the token:

```
> curl -H 'Authorization: Bearer 1cdd6dc2-42fe-4b55-b16d-78d189a88cc4' localhost:8081/products
{"error":"invalid_token","error_description":"Invalid access token: 1cdd6dc2-42fe-4b55-b16d-78d189a88cc4"}
```

This error is very consistent, I tried a lot of different changes to the configuration and even adding custom implementations of TokenServices, UserDetailsService, etc.

In the debug logs I find the following line in the output of the resource server everytime I do the request via curl:

```
Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@2b139cc0: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@b364: RemoteIpAddress: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1; SessionId: null; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
```

This is confusing to me because the Principal should not be anonymousUser in my understanding.

How can I solve this problem and request the data from my resource server? Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: If you are using spring boot starter parent above 2.0.0. CLIENT_SECRET should be encrypted in AuthserverConfiguration class.

Comment: You mean this could be the problem here? Or is it for general safety?

Comment: When i was implementing with spring boot version 2 and above, It was a problem for me please check, https://technares.home.blog